# Bad address when adding a system call

Tags: c, kernel, system-calls

I have downloaded kernel 2.6.38-5 and want to add a system call.
I did the following:

1. I have added my system call to system call table;

   ```
   <src folder>/arc/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S

   .long sys_mycall
   ```
2. I have added the system call number;

   ```
   <src folder>/include/asm-generic/unistd.h

   #define __NR_mycall 244
   __SYSCALL(__NR_mycall, sys_mycall)
   ```
3. I have added the prototype to `syscalls.h`;

   ```
   <src follder>/include/linux/syscalls.h

   asmlinkage long sys_mycall(long input);
   ```
4. And, here is my system call;

   ```
   asmlinkage long sys_mycall(long input) {
       return (input * 2);
   }
   ```
5. I have edited the Makefiles too.

Now after compilation, when I use it via `syscall()` it gives me `BAD ADDRESS` with errno set to 14.

What should I do?

Comment: +1, congratulations on having a satisfactorily complete description and minimum knowledge of your problem. You wouldn't imagine the new people coming here asking very broad questions about very low-level stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On x86, system call number 244 is already taken by [get_thread_area()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S#L246), which takes as first argument a pointer to a `struct user_desc`:

```
int get_thread_area(struct user_desc *u_info);
```

You are passing a number instead of a pointer, the kernel is trying to interpret it as a pointer, it's determining that it points outside of your process, and returning `-EFAULT`.

Comment: You are right. According to this file `/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h` the only system call number available in range 244 - 259 is 251. so i changed my system call number to 251. But this time it says: `Function not implemented` with `errno = 38`

Answer (score 0):

Syscalls query the *running* kernel. The function is mapped to an address space in the kernel. If you do not install this kernel and reboot the machine, the address will be not be valid.

Comment: Doesn't sound like an answer to me

Comment: Yes I have installed the new kernel image and kernel headers. 
But it doesn't work!